# como ponerle a un resultado de una operacion matematica los puntos de miles en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

[en mi repositorio dejo el codigo](https://github.com/Dahi25/puntos-de-mil)

Comment: Por favor [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/515118/edit) para poner el código como texto en vez de imagen; es más fácil analizar, copiar, pegar y tratar de ayudarte.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: https://github.com/Dahi25/puntos-de-mil